# Json String to HashMap

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am trying to convert a Json String to a HashMap but it is not working.
My code:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue("Json String placeholder", Map.class);
```

I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(VisibilityChecker.java:172)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:195)
.....
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another possibility to convert it? Or is anything missing?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError usually means you have a classpath problem.

Comment: Check your classpath.  Some jar file is missing.

Comment: jackson - annotiations was missing. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is not specific to your particular use with JSON but occurs if a class that was available at compile time cannot be found by JVM at runtime.  How can that happen?  Most frequently it happens if your compilation `classpath` is different from your execution one.  I have seen it happen with `ant` a lot.  Make sure the pertinent jar is included in the execution classpath.